# authorized net payment

Tags: android

I have to develop an application which do payment transfer.i have to send some important data from android to web using url.but data should not shown in url for security purpose .how i can do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to see the parameters in the query string, use the POST request instead GET request.

Also to ensure greater security, you can use a [HTTPS connection](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) instead HTTP connection.

Also, it may helps:

[Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)

[Https Connection Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android)

Other way, is using http request headers for transfering data (but is not an elegant, not good solution and unsuitable in most cases).