# User Agent in http client Android

Tags: android, http, client, user-agent

I building an Https Client to send some data to a server, but I don't know what to pass in User-Agent. Should I use the webkit one's or do I have to build one explicitely for my App?
I'm using [this handy post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)
Thanks for any help

Comment: When you say server do you mean a webserver or have you got some form of application server running?

Comment: well, I want to send a POST request to the server which will deal with the data with a php page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to pass any User-Agent header, unless you're using a service that explicitly requires it such as for tracking or debugging purposes etc.

HTTP works perfectly well without the User-Agent header being present.

Answer (score 0):

you can send:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 1.0; en-us; generic) AppleWebKit/525.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Mobile Safari/523.12.2"
that's emulator user agent string

Comment: I'll have a try with this and validate if it works. but if it's the emulator user agent string, what am I supposed to put if I want to publish my app?