# HTTPS Connection with Android

Tags: android, authentication, https

I am new on android programming and i have to create an HTTPS request to a server on my app. This server has his own certificated and is signed by VeriSign.

I read information about how to create a HTTPS request with android but all with certificated self signed or something similar. Apart from that, I have to use a username and password on that connection and I don't found any information about it.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914266/https-in-android) information about it, but I really don't understand the process about what I have to do.

Can anyone explain me how I have to send the request?

Comment: What do you mean by putting a username/password ? a BASIC authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server has a certificate signed by a certificate authority like verisign, you shouldn't do any additional stuff when making a request. Apart putting an `s` to `https` of your url, of course.

EDIT :

```
CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
http.setCredentialsProvider(credProvider);
```

Comment: oh, i am stupid ...., and about the part of use a username and password for connect with the server?

Comment: What API do you use to make your http requests ? HttpClient, URLConnection, Volley,... ?