# Connecting to a db using REST interface: Cannot connect

Tags: android, database, json, httpclient, mlab

I am trying to connect to a mongodb through mongolabs REST interface in the android app I'm developing, but it is not connecting, and instead it is throwing an exception (or at least i think it is). I am not familiar with backends, so if I am making a fatal rookie's mistake, please forgive me. This is the logcat

> 01-10 16:28:50.377: W/System.err(630): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate       didn't match:  !=  OR  OR  >01-10 16:28:50.377: W/System.err(630): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:185) 01-10 >16:28:50.388: W/System.err(630): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.verify(BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier.java:54)

Below is the part of MongoLabHelper class i wrote to access the database and get items like names

```
HttpClient client;
JSONObject db;

MongoLabHelper() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException{
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/breadcrumbs/collections/crumbs?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
    String json = in.toString();
    db = new JSONObject(json); 
}

public String getName(String name) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject doc = db.getJSONObject(name);
    return doc.getString("name");               
}
```

and here is part the class it is used in

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String name = "Crumb Not Available";

    MongoLabHelper help;
    try {
        help = new MongoLabHelper();
        name = help.getName("Chipotle");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    setContentView(R.layout.breadcrumb);
    TextView crumbName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.crumb_name);
    crumbName.setText(name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to explicitly setup the HttpClient to handle SSL.  I believe this stackoverflow thread has the information you need:

[Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)

I'll copy the relevant bit of code from the thread for convenience:

```
private HttpClient createHttpClient()
{
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

    SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
    schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
    ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a helper;
I've also implemented Android library to abstract MongoLab communication.
The main goal is to make an easy to use a library that leverages the power of Mongo in the cloud, directly from Android applications!
Note: I've also included custom ACRA reporter that uses MongoLab.

here is the first version *(I'll keep extending)*:
-> https://github.com/wareninja/mongolab-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You have an example here from an application http://lolapriego.com/blog/?p=16

or you can take a look at this Gist where you can see how to make http request in Android

```
public class CustomHttpClient {
/** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

/** Single instance of our HttpClient */
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

/**
 * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
 *
 * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
 */
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
 * specified parameters.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, JSONObject json) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        request.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;

    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;        
    } finally{
        if (in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP DELETE request to the specified url.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpDelete(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String data = null;

    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpDelete request = new HttpDelete();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(l + nl);
        }
        in.close();
        data = sb.toString();
        return data;        
    } finally{
        if (in != null){
            try{
                in.close();
                return data;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP Put request to the specified url with the
 * specified parameters.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @param putParameters The parameters to send via the request
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpPut(String url, JSONObject json) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);

        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        request.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}