# HttpURLConnection, how to sending parameters via post?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

```
    String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/foto.jpg";
    String urlServer = "http://server/upload.php";        
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";        
    .
    .
    .
    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

with the code above, i upload a image to server, but not how to pass parameters string type via post

anyone knows?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android  and this http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?tag=android-http-post link consider using HttpGet and HttpPost classes

Comment: Try my way:
[Android - HttpURLConnection parameters from Map<String, Object> via POST method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448973/android-httpurlconnection-parameters-from-mapstring-object-via-post-method)

Answer (score 0):

for each parameter, where paramName=paramData:

```
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="paramName"' + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(paramData);
```

Comment: I used  

    String param="valor";
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"param\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(param);

and does not work, 'll know it's wrong?

Comment: does it work when you remove the file submission?  Does the file need to be submitted after the param data perhaps?

Comment: done! put parameters string type after of file type parameter

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog useful for writing some multipart form data code:
http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2011/01/29/upload-using-multipart-post-using-httpclient-in-android/

Don't forget to change the `boundary` variable to match what you specify in the `HttpURLConnection` that you're using to send the multipart form to the server.