# How to pass parameters from android app to server

Tags: android, webserver, parameter-passing, multipartform-data

Can anyone tell me what's the prob with the following code?

```
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"" + lineEnd);

outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

outputStream.writeBytes("test");

outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
```

Comment: You should give us more informations about your problem. Is there any Exception? Or are there any other problems?

Comment: im getting nothing out of this . I have code for uploading and it's working fine but i need to know how can i send parameters 

check this link for hint -> 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900337/httpurlconnection-how-to-sending-parameters-via-post/12771165#12771165)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `outputStream.flush()` at the end

Comment: well the above code is followed by uploading-file code and it includes flush() is it necessary to flush this before uploading.

i need to send both key and file together .

Comment: `flush()` is like send-button, it commtis only data that goes before

Comment: this is not working kindly provide any working code of sending parameters using `HttpURLConnection` and `DataOutputStream`