# Sending information from android app to a php script

Tags: php, android

I'm neither a android or php expert, the thing is that I made a php script that gets the variables from the url ( `www.myhost.com/mailScript.php?variable1=name&variable2=age` ) and sends a mail with that information.

> Mail:
>   Variable1=Name
>   Variable2=Age

Now, the problem is that i'm makin a android app that converts a normal form, which ask name, age, etc. And i want to take that information and run php script. But i dont want the users to see a web browser at any time, just that they click de button, get the info, run the url, and done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-in-http-request-with-android). Basically, you just want to form the URL based on the value of each of your fields, then hit that URL with an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON to send data to your PHP script. 
By combining that

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

       // Execute HTTP Post Request
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   }
}
```

Source : http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

and looking about JSON, you should be able to do what you want

Comment: with the setEntity do i get the url like mailScript?id=12345&stringdata=AndDev_Is_Cool!  ??

Answer (score 0):

your php will be the server side and your android application will the be the client side you will just create a form using normal android's UI widgets. There's a plenty of examples around and send your data via HttpPost or HttpGet classes with your parameters set from this form. 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-forms/ 
and posting example [Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)