# How to make GET web service more secure

Tags: php, android, web-services

I have created web service for android in PHP that uses GET method. Now I want to convert it to POST, to make it more secure. How to convert the application from GET to POST? Is there any other way to make it more secure?

Comment: use POST in PHP file . there is no extra changes in android side.

Comment: Using `POST` doesn't secure anything... It's just another verb.  What are you trying to "secure"?

Comment: making a post does not make it any more secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on who you want to secure it from. Assuming that you want to protect from network sniffers, SSL is your best option.

POST is the weakest form of "security" you could suggest. All it does it prevent the parameters being visible in a browser's cache history (which doesn't affect you at all in this case) and make it a fraction harder to sniff the parameters over the network (which does affect you). So there's minor benefit (yes, it's worth it), but it's not secure at all.

The simplest solution is to POST using SSL. In other words, as opposed to posting to "http://example.com" you should post to "https://example.com" with a valid certificate on the server. That will encrypt the traffic between device and server. Google for suggestions, or start [Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)

Failing that, you could encrypt the data yourself and then send the encrypted query openly as only your server can decrypt it. A little bit of Googling will give you code on how to encrypt in one and decrypt in the other securely - but as a small warning, getting it to work can be frustrating as it won't work until it suddenly does... there's not much debugging you can do when it doesn't work!