# Posting data to new Google Forms

Tags: java, google-sheets, http-post, google-forms

With the previous(legacy) version of google forms it was possible to  programatically post data to the form by sending an HttpPost to a url like this:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?formkey=[key]
```

and data like this:

```
entry.1.single=data&entry.2.single=moredata
```

With the new version of google forms (released jan 2013 I think) the url structure is different. Here is a snippet from the "view live form page"

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Ee330GpkMHX_0dKWmJb6ZPdm4FBhhqJSqBbgysEtq6M/formResponse" method="POST" ...
<input type="text" name="entry.1566150510"
```

From this code snippet I would think that I could post to a url like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/[key]/formResponse
```

with data like this:

```
entry.1566150510=data
```

But I've tried that from java(android) like this:

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    Log.i(myTag, "Inside postData()");
    String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Ee330GpkMHX_0dKWmJb6ZPdm4FBhhqJSqBbgysEtq6M/formResponse";
    Log.i(myTag, "url = " + fullUrl);
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlBase);

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1566150510", "somedata"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity data = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
        Log.i(myTag, data.toString());
        httppost.setEntity(data);
        Log.i(myTag, EntityUtils.toString(data));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        Log.i("DocsUploader", "response = " + response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I get 404, not found response.

Am I missing something obvious here, or has google just removed the ability to post to the new forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, something about my use of HttpClient and HttpPost was done incorrectly. I don't know exactly what I messed up but I am now using this and it is working correctly:

```
public void postData() {
    String fullUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Ee330GpkMHX_0dKWmJb6ZPdm4FBhhqJSqBbgysEtq6M/formResponse";
    HttpRequest mReq = new HttpRequest();
    String response = mReq.sendPost(fullUrl, "entry.1566150510=data");
    Log.i(myTag, response);
}
```

Where HttpRequest is a helper class created by MattC, and posted as an answer to this question: [Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android).

Comment: How would you write this for a http action? I have:
<form method="POST" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1v6y75v5vGhFBhHGiquimY2RfK_nMR_ChdG7dRPDEPHc/formResponse">

Answer (score 2):

Consider doing the update with google-apps-script (I suspect it will be less work). And it will continue to work even if google make more tweaks.

Comment: The down side to that though is that I will have to authenticate in order to post data won't I? With the previous posting method since the form is public there was no need to authenticate before posting to it.

Comment: If you created the form, then no. No need to Authenticate. The script is owned by your google account and so it has access to all your Google drive files.