# Technologies for creating a web client for a simple Android app

Tags: android, client

This is related to a school project where we have to build a relatively simple Android app to act as an in-class survey responder. A question gets thrown up on a board and students answer through their phones, data gets passed to a small database and results get posted. Pretty simple.

My task is to find/develop a web client for this app. What are some decent technologies to do this with? Can you easily write something like this from scratch or is it better to use a sort of pre-made technology?

Comment: Web clients usually work in pair with servers, are you going to deploy a server on an Android device?

Comment: The client side as you explained you can very easily implement using just the Android Framework as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has a built in `HttpClient` API that you can use: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Another option you have is to use some 3rd party wrapper or library that simplifies your interaction with it. I have used the `HttpRequest` class which is posted in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2253280/507810 before and found it to be a bit simpler than manually using the HttpClient API

Answer (score 1):

You can create a webservice, where android phones acts as web clients. The android api has a HttpURLConnection implementation which you can use to contact the web service:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

You can use java servlets for creating the web service.