# Standard Network Request

Tags: java, android, standards, httpurlconnection

I was wondering if there is some sort of generic way to make network calls with Java / Android, as I'm struggling with my current tactics. I'm currently trying this:

```
public static File synchronousConnection(String url, String requestMethod, byte[] requestData, Map<String, String> headers)
{
    File returnData = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
        if(requestData != null && requestData.length > 0)connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(requestData.length));
        if(headers != null)for(String key : headers.keySet())connection.setRequestProperty(key, headers.get(key));
        //connection.connect();

        if(requestData != null && requestData.length > 0)
        {
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.write(requestData);

            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }

        //String response = inputStreamToString(url.openStream());
        //System.out.println("Response: " + response);

        int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        connection.disconnect();

        System.out.println("Status code: " + statusCode);

        //returnData = response;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IO Exception in connections\n" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid information for network connection\n" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnData;
}
```

I have a fair bit of components commented out, as they seemed to interfere with the process or bring up issues, even though they were in other examples. As for `inputStreamToString(InputStream)`, that is one of my methods to do just what it says.

Is there a generic way to a URL connection, given my input parameters to the function? Currently, I'm really struggling to get any connections to work and its odd to have to do things in a custom way for each request. Also, I can't seem to get any response data back from a `POST` request, even though my API does return a response body.

Comment: try using the HttpRequest wrapper that is provided in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2253280/507810 that simplifies the process of making http requests.

Comment: @FoamyGuy That looks amazing! However, is there a way to send PUT and DELETE?

Comment: @FoamyGuy Also, from the looks of it, there doesn't seem to be a real standard way to perform network calls, right?

Comment: @RileyE : What is a "standard" network request/call by your definition? There are very many network protocols and data encoding mechanisms...what are you trying to do that needs to be "standard"?

Comment: @Squonk You are correct that there are many different protocol and data encoding mechanisms, however, if you take a look at my example method, it has all of that taken care of before even reaching the request. I'm looking for a way to make calls to a server given all variances in the parameters. I can do it easily enough in iOS and I was hoping to have a similar experience with Android.