# Login to DB and extract info BEST PRACTICE?

Tags: android, authentication, database-connection

I have already framed the connection between the app and the db on my web server using JSON(the app extracts the info using the JSON) although I have second thoughts in this type of connection I have no other way in my experience in Android to securely access the DB.

what I really want is to extract the information from the DB and load a specific XML file for the UI of the app for example:

The user is given a login box that has username and password then using JSON the data is received from a table in the db which is checked within the app and load the corresponding information(that is in the other columns) from the same table.

How to go about doing all this securely and at the same time efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer [Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android) for an explanation of how to handle HTTPS in android.

Comment: So all people use HTTP Post to handle login processes in Android?

Comment: Well that depends, are you accessing your DB through HTTP?

Comment: yes accessing it through HTTP requests and accessing the JSON which is generated by a PHP script

Comment: Well then SSL is the way to go. :)

Comment: I looked at the link and the most accepted answer my namely the "MattC"  and my code that I currently implement seems the same and there nothing unique there

Comment: Well do you have SSL set up on the server?

Comment: i think its just the plain Apache HTTP server running nothing special done to it

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong NO ON MY WEBSERVER I'm not using any SSL