# Android Upload file in a specified $_POST field

Tags: android, xml, post

i need to upload a very small sized .xml file to a php script.
This script will parse the file, create some stuff on a map, and then the application will display the result.

The problem is that, if i have to upload a file with an html page, i create a form, put an input field with "name=userfile" and then server side i find it in $_FILES['userfile'].

How to do this in android? with string is very simple with

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add("key", "value");
```

but now?

this is my code client side but no file seems to hit the server:

```
final String url = "http://www.blablabladasdasd/mysite/test.php";
    String selected = getIntent().getStringExtra("com.example.ghghgh.filename");
    final File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/myFolder/"+selected + ".xml");
    Log.i("FILE SIZE: ", "" + file.length());

    final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());



    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            client.getParams().setParameter("userfile", file);

            try
            {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.i("RESPONSE: ", res);
                mWebView.loadData(res, "text/html", HTTP.UTF_8);

            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();

    try
    {
        thread.join();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve a similar issue, and found my answers right here:
http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/
Basically, life gets easier with a few extra Apache libraries. As a bonus, here is how to do the same thing, but over a secure (SSL) connection:
[Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)

You might be misinterpreting the docs for loadData, as it expects 'base64' or URL encoded data, otherwise. Not XML or HTML. Perhaps loadURL works better?

Hope this helps

Comment: I come from something similar, and i had problem with deprecated object, btw i will make another try with your link thank you

Comment: mmh something is happen, i have the entire response html code in the string "res" but when i try "loadData(res, "text/html", HTTP.UTF_8)" it doesn't display the page