# Secure HTTPS POST in Android

Tags: android, rest, post, https, socketfactory

I'm a noob with Android development, so bear with me. I'm trying to figure out how to make a secure HTTPS POST in Android for a REST API call, and I tried the following method (provided at [Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android))

```
private HttpClient createHttpClient()
{
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

    SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
    schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
    ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
}
```

However, I pasted this into my code, and I think I imported everything that's necessary, but Eclipse is complaining about this line:

```
schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
```

It says "The method getSocketFactory() is undefined for the type SSLSocketFactory". Has this been deprecated, and is there a newer way to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was. I was importing javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory instead of org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory. Eclipse automatically added the wrong import statement.

Thanks to the comment located at http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/31/creating-an-http-client-example/#comment-77