# Android application - post data to a Google form

Tags: java, android, post, google-forms

I have a problem with my android application. I am trying to make the users fill out a form in the application and send their responses to a Google form online, which would record the responses in a Google spreadsheet. Everything seems fine in the application itself and I encounter no errors there, but only the timestamp shows in the response spreadsheet and no text.

This is my code for the postData method:

```
public void postData(){
   String url = getString(R.string.post_URL);
   String name = "testname";
   Log.i("test",name);
   String lunch = "testlunch";
   Log.i("test", lunch);
   String vegetarian="testveg";
   Log.i("test",vegetarian);
   String allergies = "testaler";
   Log.i("test",allergies);
   String special = "testspec";
   Log.i("test",special);
   HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
       try {
           String data = R.string.entry_name + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                R.string.entry_lunch + URLEncoder.encode(lunch, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                R.string.entry_vegetarian + URLEncoder.encode(vegetarian, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                R.string.entry_allergies + URLEncoder.encode(allergies, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                R.string.entry_special + URLEncoder.encode(special,"UTF-8");

        String response = request.sendPost(url,data);
        Log.i("response",response);
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        Log.d("Unsupported exception", e.toString());
    }}
```

I'm using this URL of the google form:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XPaQe0j86XwcxbO13uxZRawCwUexyJMHdPlPLoQaD1A/formResponse
```

For the entries, I am using strings formatted like this:

```
entry.569049980
```

This is how I call the function (only temporarily):

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Connection().execute();
}

private class Connection extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object...arg0){
        postData();
        return null;
    }
```

The HttpRequest file, which I am using comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

/*
 * This helper class was created by StackOverflow user: MattC        https://stackoverflow.com/users/21126/mattc
* IT was posted as an Answer to this question:      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android
*/

public class HttpRequest {

   DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
   HttpContext localContext;
   private String ret;

   HttpResponse response = null;
   HttpPost httpPost = null;
   HttpGet httpGet = null;

public HttpRequest(){
    HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
    localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
}

public void clearCookies() {
    httpClient.getCookieStore().clear();
}

public void abort() {
    try {
        if (httpClient != null) {
            System.out.println("Abort.");
            httpPost.abort();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Your App Name Here" + e);
    }
}

public String sendPost(String url, String data) {
    return sendPost(url, data, null);
}

public String sendJSONPost(String url, JSONObject data) {
    return sendPost(url, data.toString(), "application/json");
}

public String sendPost(String url, String data, String contentType) {
    ret = null;

   // httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter( ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,
            CookiePolicy.NETSCAPE );
    httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    response = null;

    StringEntity tmp = null;

    Log.d("Your App Name Here", "Setting httpPost headers");

    httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "SET YOUR USER AGENT STRING HERE");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*;q=0.5");

    if (contentType != null) {
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
    } else {
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }

    try {
        tmp = new StringEntity(data,"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("Your App Name Here", "HttpUtils : UnsupportedEncodingException : " + e);
    }

    httpPost.setEntity(tmp);

    Log.d("Your App Name Here", url + "?" + data);

    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);

        if (response != null) {
            ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Your App Name Here", "HttpUtils: " + e);
    }

    Log.d("Your App Name Here", "Returning value:" + ret);

    return ret;
}

public String sendGet(String url) {
    httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Your App Name Here", e.getMessage());
    }

    //int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    // we assume that the response body contains the error message
    try {
        ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Your App Name Here", e.getMessage());
    }

    return ret;
}

public InputStream getHttpStream(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    } // end try-catch

    return in;
   }
 }
```

Do I need to use the Drive API or can I make some modifications to make this work? (This seems to be much easier and I am not experienced at all with the Drive API)

Answer (score 0):

You entries format should be "entry_number" and some corrections in your data. Hope this will help you.

```
String data = "entry_number1lkjhgfdrtyuo=" + URLEncoder.encode(col1) + "&" +
            "entry_number2=" + URLEncoder.encode(col2) + "&" +
            "entry_number3=" + URLEncoder.encode(col3);
```