# Sending Data to a Google Spreadsheet from and Android App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-sheets

I'm making an app where I want to store data the users input on a google spreadsheet. I have tried [Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android/2253280#2253280) already and the first answer does not work when I put it in android studio. Does anyone know another way to send data from an app to the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

use retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Setup a post method like this

```
@POST("users/data")
Call<Data> storeData(@Body Data data);
```

Then make the post call by calling the method with correct data.

All http methods are implemented in similar fashion.
Refer docs for detailed information about how to use retrofit.